# tooltip is shown after the 2nd hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a problem, I'm trying to add a tooltip to some already rendered elements. The code that I have makes the tooltip appear after the 2nd hover which is kind of normal because on the first one is not set yet, do you know what can I do to have it displayed from the first hover?

Thanks in advance!

I have the following code:

```
$(".checkWidth").live("mouseenter",function() {
  var size = measureText($(this).text(), 12, 'Tahoma')
  var limit = $('#my_container').width() - 67;

  if( size.width > limit){

    $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());

    $('#tiptip_content').css('font-size', '13px');

    $(this).tipTip({
      maxWidth: "auto",
      defaultPosition: "right",
      fadeIn: 100,
      fadeIn: 100,
      attribute: "title"
    });
 }
```

});

Comment: Do you get an error the first time you hover? Also, use jQuery's .on() method instead of .live() as it has been depreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation about using on() instead, no I don't get an error is just that I need to leave the element and then enter again to see the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$(this).tipTip({...});` **sets up** the tooltip, it doesn't show it. So you don't actually set up the tooltip until you mouseover the element, and the tooltip is shown the next time you mouse over (handled by the plugin).

You'll need to call that on DOM ready. I think you may need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#tiptip_content').css('font-size', '13px');
    var limit = $('#my_container').width() - 67;

    $('.checkWidth').each(function () {
        var size = measureText($(this).text(), 12, 'Tahoma');

        if (size.width > limit) {

            $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());

            $(this).tipTip({
                maxWidth: "auto",
                defaultPosition: "right",
                fadeIn: 100,
                fadeIn: 100,
                attribute: "title"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit** another possibility:

```
$('#tiptip_content').css('font-size', '13px'); //this should be able to be done elsewhere...

$("document").on("mouseenter", '.checkWidth', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.data('tipInit') === true) { return; }
    $this.data('tipInit', true);

    var size = measureText($(this).text(), 12, 'Tahoma')
    var limit = $('#my_container').width() - 67;

    if (size.width > limit) {

        $this.attr('title', $this.text());

        $this.tipTip({
            maxWidth: "auto",
            defaultPosition: "right",
            fadeIn: 100,
            fadeIn: 100,
            attribute: "title"
        });

        $this.trigger('mouseenter');        
    }    

});
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, but at the beginning the elements are not there yet :(

Comment: Then you'll need to set up your tooltips in (I assume) your ajax callback that creates them. But waiting until mouseover is too late.

Comment: Yes I know is too late, the elements are part of a chosen element, the thing is that they are generated by a library and I don't have control, I tried to add this code here: $("#chosen_element").on("liszt:showing_dropdown", function () but is a big list and takes like 14 secs to check the length of every element and add the tooltip to the long ones. :'( I'm suffering

Comment: See my edit. Maybe you can just retrigger the mouseenter event.

Comment: I owe you a big box of Belgium chocolates!!! That worked, actually I added trigger to my .live() function. I tried this before but it got into a dead loop so I added the extra if you suggested and it worked :) :) :) :) :) :) :) Thanks a lot for expending time helping me :)!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your code structure. But I will try the following:

- Try changing the .live() to .on()
- I would try to change the function to .on('hover', function)
- I would also try to use mousenter and mouseleave